# How to execute an update on multiple rows using Linq Lambda Expression in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I'm having a hard time trying to execute an update on multiple rows in a table.

I've tried this code:

```
PayoutEntities payoutdb = new PayoutEntities();

public void SaveStatusBatch(string batchid)
{
   payout_transaction data = payoutdb.payout_transaction.Where(x => x.batchid == batchid).FirstOrDefault();
   data.status = "Success";
   payoutdb.SaveChanges();
}
```

But it only updates only a single row where the batchid is a match to what is indicated in the parameter. I'm using `Èntity Framework` in this.

This is how my table looks like:

```
|batchid|name|status|
|1      |John|      |
|1      |Nick|      |
|1      |Bill|      |
|2      |Ara |      |
```

I wanted to update the status of John,Nick and Bill to Success. 
Do you have any suggestions on how am i supposed to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept is to change all the data and then call the `SaveChanges` of the DBContext object. e.g.:

```
public void SaveStatusBatch(string batchid)
{
      payout_transaction data = payoutdb.payout_transaction
        .Where(x => x.batchid == batchid)
        .ToList();

      data.ForEach(a=> a.status = "Success");
      payoutdb.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this i didn't thought it was this easy :)

Comment: Glad that it helped :)